# Timeline using multiline notes

Tags: timeline

Dear TeX Stackexchange,

I am trying to make a timeline using multiline notes using the *chronosys* package.

This is how it looks without the vpsace*
[image]

This is how it looks with the vspace*
[image]

Here is my Minimal Working Example (MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{84CECC}
\definecolor{gr}{HTML}{375D81}

\begin{document}


\startchronology[align=left, startyear=2012,stopyear=2018, height=0pt, startdate=false, stopdate=false, dateselevation=0pt, arrow=false, box=true]
%
\chronograduation[event][dateselevation=0pt]{1}
%---------------------periods----------------%
\chronoperiode[textstyle=\raggedleft\colorbox{gr!50}, color=gr, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=8pt, textdepth=-25pt,dateselevation=16pt, stopdate=false]{2013}{2014}{%
\begin{varwidth}{3cm}\vspace*{-2cm}Modular body. Modular base electronics.         
Modular Leg Module\end{varwidth}}

\stopchronology
\end{document}
```

I am wondering what the proper way is to have multiline notes in this timeline. I want to add notes for 2014-2015, 2015-2016, 2016-2017 and 2017-2018 aswell.
With kind regards,
Zhendos.

Comment: I would look in the manual for a parameter to set, like `dateselevation`.